# Writing an efficient backtrace function

Tags: c++, assembly, gdb, x86-64, tcmalloc

I came across below code for walking backtrace

```
struct stack_frame {
  struct stack_frame *prev;
    void *return_addr;
} __attribute__((packed));
typedef struct stack_frame stack_frame;

__attribute__((noinline, noclone))
void backtrace_from_fp(void **buf, int size)
{
    int i;
    stack_frame *fp;

    __asm__("movl %%ebp, %[fp]" :  /* output */ [fp] "=r" (fp));

    for(i = 0; i < size && fp != NULL; fp = fp->prev, i++)
        buf[i] = fp->return_addr;
}
```

the reason behind looking for this code is we are using a 3rd party malloc hook hence don't want to use backtrace which again allocates memory. Above doesn't work for x86_64 and I modified asm statement to

```
    __asm__("movl %%rbp, %[fp]" :  /* output */ [fp] "=r" (fp));
```

I get crash

```
(gdb) bt
#0  backtrace_from_fp (size=10, buf=<optimized out>) at src/tcmalloc.cc:1910
#1  tc_malloc (size=<optimized out>) at src/tcmalloc.cc:1920
#2  0x00007f5023ade58d in __fopen_internal () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#3  0x00007f501e687956 in selinuxfs_exists () from /lib64/libselinux.so.1
#4  0x00007f501e67fc28 in init_lib () from /lib64/libselinux.so.1
#5  0x00007f5029a32503 in _dl_init_internal () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#6  0x00007f5029a241aa in _dl_start_user () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#7  0x0000000000000001 in ?? ()
#8  0x00007fff22cb8e24 in ?? ()
#9  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
(gdb)
(gdb) p $rbp
$2 = (void *) 0x7f501e695f37
(gdb) p (stack_frame *)$rbp
$3 = (stack_frame *) 0x7f501e695f37
(gdb) p *$3
$4 = {prev = 0x69662f636f72702f, return_addr = 0x6d6574737973656c}
(gdb) x /1xw 0x69662f636f72702f
0x69662f636f72702f:     Cannot access memory at address 0x69662f636f72702f
(gdb) fr
#0  backtrace_from_fp (size=10, buf=<optimized out>) at src/tcmalloc.cc:1910
1910    in src/tcmalloc.cc
(gdb)
```

Am I missing something ?. Any help on how can I reconstruct the same via code ?.

Comment: movq is needed in 64-bit mode instead of movl: `__asm__("movq %%rbp, %[fp]" :  /* output */ [fp] "=r" (fp));`

Comment: If you are using gcc, you can use the various [return address builtins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Return-Address.html).

Comment: You cannot rely on `rbp` being the frame pointer, because sane software doesn't *use* frame pointers any more. Frame pointers are a relic of (bad) assembly programing and bad compilers, with bad debug info. There is no *need* for frame pointers when you have reasonably good tooling, so modern toolchains instead use the `rbp` register as a general-purpose register, which speeds up the code without any relevant downside.

Comment: @Jester Even I want to do the same, but the problem is I am not sure how many frames are there and hence calling this builtin with an index not present results in crashing.

Comment: It would normally return 0 before crashing though, just as your very own `fp != NULL` condition.

Comment: @Renat I changed the same but still not able to reconstruct the backtrace, I see the same working with my sample program, but when I build this with my product I hit this crash.

Answer (score 3):

> Am I missing something ?

The code you referenced *assumes* the compiled code is using frame pointer register chain.

This was the default on (32-bit) `i*86` up until about 5-7 years ago, and has not been the default on `x86_64` since ~forever.

The code will most likely work fine in non-optimized builds, but will fail miserably with optimization on both 32-bit and 64-bit x86 platforms using non-ancient versions of the compiler.

If you can rebuild *all* code (including `libc`) with `-fno-omit-frame-pointer`, then this code will work most of the time (but not *all* the time, because `libc` may have hand-coded assembly, and that assembly will not have frame pointer chain).

One solution is to use [libunwind](https://www.nongnu.org/libunwind/). Unfortunately, using it from inside `malloc` can still run into a [problem](https://github.com/gperftools/gperftools/issues/225), if you (or any libraries you use) also use `dlopen`.

Comment: I would guess that all of glibc's hand-written asm functions are leaf functions; they aren't part of anything else's call chain via callbacks, and they don't call `malloc`.  examples include `memcpy`, `strchr`, and a few FP math functions for some ISAs.

Comment: re: avoiding malloc: perhaps you could compile `libunwind` to use a custom allocator that uses raw `mmap` directly, if it doesn't have to be fast.  Or a separate simple malloc/free.  As long as its allocations don't need to be compatible with the real `free`.

Comment: @PeterCordes I vaguely remember hand-written assembly functions calling initializers (which can then call anything). And `libunwind` already doesn't call `malloc`. But it has to call `dl_iterate_phdr`, which requires the loader lock, when may be acquired before malloc lock. Gory details: https://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/libunwind-devel/2010-05/msg00006.html

Comment: Maybe just selection bias on my part from having only looked at performance-relevant but simple functions.  I can't think of any that would need to init a lookup table but are written in asm; e.g. the char classification functions like `isalnum` are written in C.  But sure, could be something.